# Examples of how to process xsl transformations in Java

Tags: java, xml, xslt

I have the following question: Is there any example of how to process xsl transformation?
I know that I can use the Transformer class (XSL API) but I want to know something more about the background work so I can adopt it for other languages/systems.
I already read some xsl tutorials but there are only descriptions about how xsl is structured and the meaning of the tags but I found no overview about the steps to process.

Comment: Maybe this can help you. Xalan is one of transformers from XML with XSLT.
There is the API: [Xalan 2.7.1](https://xml.apache.org/xalan-j/apidocs/index.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might help you to know that the native API for XSLT transformations is called JAXP. If you google for "JAXP Transformation API examples" you will find many sites that give examples and tutorials - it's hard for me to advise which you should go to first, because everyone's learning style is different.

You need to be aware that the built-in XSLT engine in the JDK (a version of Xalan) is very old, and only supports the XSLT 1.0 language which came out in 1999. Unless you have strong reasons to use XSLT 1.0, you should really be using something more up to date (XSLT 2.0 came out in 2007, XSLT 3.0 in 2017). These versions are supported by third-party products such as Saxon. Saxon supports the JAXP API, but if you want to take advantage of all the features of XSLT 2.0/3.0 then you're better off using Saxon's native API, known as s9api (pronounced "snappy"). You can find examples of that in the documentation and resource downloads at www.saxonica.com.